# How do I fix the arms and legs on this model?

Tags: rigging

My student used Rigify to build the rig for his model. When he tries to pose the arms, the gauntlets do not move with the rig/arms. He says that he has joined the gauntlets to the rig. Also, when he moves the legs, the legs of the model move in the opposite direction of the rig. I have attached two screenshots illustrating the problems. How would my student resolve these issues? I can attach the blend file as well.
[[image: Here you can see that the gauntlets do not move with the model/rig.Here you can see that the legs move in the opposite direction of the rig.]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello, moonboots! I have uploaded the file via the link you provided.

Comment: you need to copy paste the URL it has created  ;)

Comment: My apologies. First time using pasteall.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/39f0a6549403428e8cc200f3b1045355

Comment: Thank you very much, moonboots!

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to do:

Apply the scale of both the armature and the mesh:

[image]

Recalculate the normals of the mesh (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Parent again *With Automatic Weights*. For the gauntlets, as they are not supposed to bend as the rest of the body, select them, on the right of the vertex groups list click on *Remove from All Groups* then assign to the good bone (like for example *forearm.R*):

[image]

Put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer, moonboots! I appreciate you greatly.